# Need help writing an XpathQueryString

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to write an XPath to pull the value 55.3469 from the tag below., but I am not sure where to start.

```
<tr class="uccRes">
<td width="47%" align="right" class="leftCol">100.00&nbsp;<span   class="uccResCde">ALL</span><!-- This is test data. -->
</td>
<td width="6%" valign="middle" align="center">=</td>
<td width="47%" align="left" class="rightCol">55.3469&nbsp;<span class="uccResCde">AFN</span><!-- This is test data. -->
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The [WC3 XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/) seems like a good place.

Comment: If you ask for code help, tell us want kind of code you use (PHP, Javascript,...)

Comment: Also, you have a lot of questions without [an accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Go through them and see if any of the answers deserve being accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the `span` with `AFN` text and `class="uccResCde"`, then get the `preceding-sibling`:

```
//span[@class='uccResCde' and text()='AFN']/preceding-sibling::text()
```